# Driver Cannot Started?

Tags: windows-7, driver, wdk

I have created a driver for SSDT shadow hooking.The driver created successfully in windows 7 environment using wdk.Whenever i try to start the service of driver  using osrloader I got an error like parameter incorrect or system cannot find the file specified  .I can able to register the service but I am unable to start the service.I have verified that HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\XXXX image name and path  are correct.How to resolve this error?

Comment: Post some more details of your problem.

Comment: Check the .sys files dependencies on other dlls. You can use _depends_ do that and verify dlls exists.

Comment: Rohan@ sorry i can not get you what u have said.Can u explain berifly

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling driver signing.

You can do this permanently with bcdedit.exe, or just test it out by pressing `F8` when your computer boots and select the `Disable Driver Signature Enforcement` option.